# How to make custom buttons in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, interface

Do you know of any tutorial that could help me make a custom button in vb.net. Because visual studio 2008 doesn't allow you to create buttons in circle or triangular shapes. I've tried searching and found this one but, I cannot make use of it because there are lots of errors. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/CButton.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use WPF to create any shape of Button.

see below URL

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/glassbuttons.aspx

Comment: how do I use it to style buttons,

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom buttons of various shapes is super easy, 
Here is the basic code after you add a picture box to your form (picHome):

```html
    Private Sub picHome_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles picHome.Click
        Try
            Dim tPic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
            If Not IsNothing(tPic.Image) Then
                tPic.Image.Dispose()
                tPic.Image = Nothing
            End If
            tPic.Image = Global.CustomButton.My.Resources.btnDemoHome30_MOver
            lbMsg.Text = "HOME BUTTON CLICKED"
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub picHome_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles picHome.MouseDown
        Try
            Dim tPic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
            If Not IsNothing(tPic.Image) Then
                tPic.Image.Dispose()
                tPic.Image = Nothing
            End If
            tPic.Image = Global.CustomButton.My.Resources.btnDemoHome30_MClick
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub picHome_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles picHome.MouseEnter
        Try
            Dim tPic As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
            If Not IsNothing(tPic.Image) Then
                tPic.Image.Dispose()
                tPic.Image = Nothing
            End If
            tPic.Image = Global.CustomButton.My.Resources.btnDemoHome30_MOver
            lbMsg.Text = "MOUSE OVER HOME BUTTON"
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

To see it in action watch this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=989M3qYrlKo , if you still have any questions post back here.